# Changes to a parent element's textContent causes the child to delete

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a 'click' event on an image in javascript that I want to use to change the text content of the parent element when clicked. However, when I click it, the parent's text changes, but the image deletes itself. I assume I can just create and append a new child element after, but this doesn't seem to be the most efficient, and I would also like to understand why the child element gets deleted. My code looks like the following:

```
<body>
  <ul>
    <li> Hello <img src="img/hello.png"></li>
  <ul>
<body>
<script>
  const helloImage = document.querySelector('img')
  helloImage.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let parentEle = e.target.parentElement
    parentEle.textContent = 'bye'
  })
<script>
```

I have looked for a while for an answer, but can't seem to find anything with regards to modern javascript. I found one answer to a similar question with jQuery, but I got the same result when applying the solution's logic. Any help or if you can just point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: The image is part of the content of its parent, so it will be replaced if you set its `textContent`. You have to separate the text you want to change in a different element, say a `span` and change the content of _that_ element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `textContent` you overwrite all other child nodes.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent):

> Warning: Setting textContent on a node removes all of the node's children and replaces them with a single text node with the given string value.

The [corresponding spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-node-textcontent) for the `textContent` setter says

> String replace all with the given value within this.

If you only want to change the text then alter your HTML and wrap the text you want to change in a distinct element. Then reference that element's `textContent` in the click handler.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify the HTML-Structure, in order to select the textContent directly, an approach is to copy all the child nodes of the label except the textContent and copy them back after the content was changed.

```
// Get the label you want to change
let label = document.getElementById("myLabelToChange");
// Copy the children to another array which is not updated by the node itself
let childrenStatic = [];
for (let i = 0; i < label.childNodes.length; i++){
  // Skip the text node itself
  if (label.childNodes[i].nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE)  
    continue;
  childrenStatic.push(label.childNodes[i]); // Take all other nodes
}
label.textContent = "new text of label"; // Change the text
// re-append all other nodes that 
for (let i = 0; i < childrenStatic.length; i++){
  label.appendChild(childrenStatic[i]);
}
```

This works very well in my use-case, where the textContent is the first child. In other cases it might mess up the structure and further measures must be taken.

Answer (score 0):

That's worked for me:

```
 const helloImage = document.querySelector('img');
  helloImage.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    helloImage.previousSibling.replaceData(0, 7, 'bye')
  })
```

Better late, than never :)